# MacOS Bash command line overlap

Tags: bash, macos, command-line

I am new to Bash and just set my own terminal theme. However, when I typed a long command, the command line overlapped in one line instead of wrapping into two. I looked up for solutions and solved the problem by making sure I added \[...\] when using non-printing characters in a bash prompt. Yet, when I move up and down my cursor on previous command line, the command line still overlaps like this:

```
katnano .bash_profile
```

while normally it should be:

```
katrinachan@katrina :~$ nano .bash_profile
```

My .bash_profile looks like this:

```
export PS1="\[\e[1;38;5;73m\u@\h\e[m\] :\[\e[1;38;5;214m\W\e[m\]\$ "
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=Cxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
```

May I know what I am missing in my .bash_profile file? Thanks

[Solved]

Thank you! It works perfectly. Now my code is:

```
export PS1="[\e[1;38;5;73m]\u@\h[\e[m] :[\e[1;38;5;214m]\W[\e[m]\$ " 
export CLICOLOR=1 
export LSCOLORS=Cxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
```

The overlap problem doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\[...\]` should *only* bracket sequences which do not involve cursor movement on output.  You have the `\u@\h\e` sequence inside these brackets where obviously it should be outside.